# replace " in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, replace, escaping

How can I replace the double quote in VB.NET?

This code doesn't work:

```
name.Replace("""," ")
```

Answer (score 21):

You need to use a double quote within those quotes (and get the return value - String.Replace does not operate on the string itself, it returns a new string):

```
name = name.Replace(""""," ")
```

Comment: That'll do the replace, but being a fragment seems to give the impression it will happen in place. It won't, a new string is returned (I'm sure *you* know that, just saying I'd make it clear in the answer).

Answer (score 20):

Instead of a "data link escaped" method of...

```
name = name.Replace("""", "")
```

You could be explicit and somewhat more readable...

```
name = name.Replace(ControlChars.DblQuote, "")
```

And BTW, instead of thinking of this as returning a NEW STRING; it's better to think of the REPLACE as a part of the STRING Class associated with the 'name' instance. If it's losing the old value of name that you do not want then simply...

```
Dim aNewString$ = name.Replace(ControlChars.DblQuote, "")
```

And the 'name' will remain unchanged.

Comment: This work for me, I try paxdiablo sugestion, and it work too, but I ended keeping Curt's sugestion,   Thank you both.

Comment: What .Net version had `DblQuote` constant? It appears that [it has always been `Quote`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.controlchars?view=netframework-1.1) for a double-quote.

Answer (score 8):

```
name = name.Replace(Chr(34), "")
```

Comment: http://yorktown.cbe.wwu.edu/sandvig/shared/ASCIICodes.aspx provide list of ASCII character available.

Answer (score 0):

you should return the resultant string back to a string and also escape that double quotes with a double quote or "\"

```
name = name.Remove("""", String.Empty)
```

Comment: You can't escape strings in VB.Net

Comment: That is not how [String.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netcore-3.1) is used.

Answer (score 0):

I had a nasty one where try as I might, I could not get `Replace()` to work. In the end, it turned out the strings I was trying to clean somehow had got a completely different characters which just LOOKED like double quotes.  A genius had edited a script file using Word, so `"hello"` became `“hello”`.  Subtle, or what?
Looking at the file with a hex editor, the opening quote was the three character value `0xe2 0x80 0x9c`, and the closer was `0xe2 0x80 0x9d`.  No wonder the replace failed!

Answer (score -1):

'This part is to remove the " mark in the string

```
Dim GetDate31 As String = Date31(16).Replace(Chr(34), "")
```