# vb.net: Replace function with double quotes in From part

Tags: vb.net, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [replace " in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452906/replace-in-vb-net)

in vb.net how can i use replace function when the **replace from** part has double quotes in its value ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim s As String = String.Replace("some string", "some "" string with quotes")
```