# How to put data containing double-quotes in string variable?

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [replace " in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452906/replace-in-vb-net)

How to put data containing double-quotes in string variable?
Aug 01, 2003 02:30 AM | LINK

I need to store a string that contains words in double quotes. The complete string data is presented to the variable in double quotes, but the next double quotes within the data ends the string and the remaining text gives a syntax error. How can I place literal double-quotes in a string variable? For example:

```
Dim MyVar as string = "stm_bm(["menu53d0",400,"","blank2.gif",0,"","",0,0,250,0,1000,1,0,0,""],this);"
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can escape (this is how this principle is called) the double quotes by prefixing them with another double quote. You can put them in a string as follows:

```
Dim MyVar as string = "some text ""hello"" hello"
```

This will give the `MyVar` variable a value of `some text "hello" hello`.