# MYSQL command string being cut

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have this code on my program

```
strSQL = "load data local infile 'C:/csv.csv' replace into table student_records fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\r\n'"
```

but the string it considers is only `"load data local infile 'C:/csv.csv' replace into table student_records fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"`

and this is considered a comment`' lines terminated by '\r\n'"`

the string is being terminated by the double quote while it is still part of my mysql command.

can you give me another way around on how to do this?

i'm trying to automate the updating of data in my table.

Comment: Take a look at here - How to put data containing double-quotes in string variable


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767037/how-to-put-data-containing-double-quotes-in-string-variable

Answer (score -1):

Try escaping double quotes with "\" character:

```
strSQL = "load data local infile 'C:/csv.csv' replace into table student_records fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"' lines terminated by '\r\n'"
```