# add " into String variable

Tags: vb.net

As the question state, I need to add the **"** character into a string variable. Is it possible ?
I tried `Keys.OemQuote.ToString` ... and to my surprise, it says that that key is Oem7. They both share the same key code of 222 ?

So now I'm stuck, and I can't search anything related to that **"** since godgle  filter it out automatically.

I need it since my application have to work with an excel file in which i need to put the **"** into one of the cell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767037/how-to-put-data-containing-double-quotes-in-string-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

```
Dim someString As String = "Hello " & Chr(34) & "World" & Chr(34)
Dim someString2 As String = "Hello ""World"""
```

Possibly you're worried about Unicode here... but if this is a some unicode character that is only similar to the ascii 34 double-quote, VB.Net has unicode support in the language. Just paste the character into a string literal.

Comment: Personally, I would consider that first one a poor option. If you're going to use concatenation instead of escaping then `ControlChars.Quote` is the better option as it's self-documenting.

Comment: Both someString2 and ControlChars.Quote did the trick for me. Thank you. Yeah, agree with jmcilhinney, i prefer the second too.

Answer (score -3):

In Java, you can use the escape character '\' before quotation marks to make them a part of the string. Like this:

```
String test = "This is a \"test\".";
```

Possibly vb.net has the same functionality

Comment: VB.Net does not have escaped strings. There are no \r, \n, \t, \0, \" etc

Comment: That is how it's done in C-based languages, including Java and C#.  VB.NET is based on VB syntax.