# How to work with quotation marks as code and in string

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, parsing, escaping

I am creating a program in VB.net which downloads a website source code, which will then allow me to search for certain piecese of code to determine the server status of a game (website here: https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/200426246) without actually visiting the page. The problem is, most of the website code has quotation mark inside of it, which ends the program quotation marks at the wrong place causing errors, for example:

```
If (sourceString).Contains(<div class="panel-base xbl" style="background-color: rgb(236, 255, 236);"><div class="marshmallowLogo" id="xboxLogo">Xbox 360</div>
        <center><span class="statusSpan" style="color: green;">Up</span>
        </center>")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put data containing double-quotes in string variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767037/how-to-put-data-containing-double-quotes-in-string-variable)

Comment: I'm having problems with following that, I was hoping someone could show me an example using the code I provided, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

define a double quote char:

```
Private Const QUOTE As Char = """"c
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
 If (sourceString).Contains($"< div class={QUOTE}panel-base xbl{QUOTE} style={QUOTE}background-color: RGB(236, 255, 236);{QUOTE}><div class={QUOTE}marshmallowLogo{QUOTE} id={QUOTE}xboxLogo{QUOTE}>Xbox 360</div><center><span class={QUOTE}statusSpan{QUOTE} style={QUOTE}color green;{QUOTE}>Up</span></center>") Then

 End If
```

This requires VS2015 - if you have an earlier version use `String.Format` instead of the `$""`

Answer (score -1):

double quote ""

"< div class=""panel-base xbl"" style

or

"< div class='panel-base xbl' style

Thanks

Comment: you mean double double quote