# How to properly format mysql query in .Net

Tags: mysql, string, vb.net, string-formatting

can someone help me to format the following string in vb.net?

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("\"", a.myCol, "\"") ORDER BY a.id ASC SEPARATOR ', ') FROM `table` a
```

I am trying the following way but I don't know how to properly format in vb.net so that I can run above mentioned query in mysql.

```
 Dim str As String = String.Format("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(" \ "", a.myCol, "\"") ORDER BY a.id ASC SEPARATOR ', ') FROM `table` a")

            MsgBox(str)
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Never concatenate parameter values manually, use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection

Comment: If this is only your Query.. It is a bad format. My Question is.. What do you want to do exactly? do you have  a sample data to show and  the desired output?

Comment: Nobody should help you with this. It's bad practice to concatenate queries. Use [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html)

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET double quotes indicate the strart and end of a string. You need to have [2 double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767037/how-to-put-data-containing-double-quotes-in-string-variable) when you want one in the string.

```
Dim str As String = String.Format("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(""\"""", a.myCol, ""\"""") ORDER BY a.id ASC SEPARATOR ', ') FROM `table` a")
```