# ADODB Connection string from Word to Excel not working

Tags: vba, connection-string, adodb

Sorry for posting again, but my brain is fried. Where is the syntax error in this connection string?  I'm getting "Compile error. Expected: end of statement" in the myConn with block.

```
Sub Letter3()
Dim mySQLquery As String
Dim myKey As String
Dim mySource As String
Dim slkAddresseeName, slkCompanyInfo, slkRegarding, slkFileNum, slkSalutation As String
Dim slkTemplate As String
Dim myConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim myRs As ADODB.Recordset

mySource = "C:\LetterMemoDB.xls"
mySQLquery = "SELECT * FROM " & mySource & " WHERE LoginID = '" & myKey & "'"
myConn = New ADODB.Connection
myRs = New ADODB.Recordset

With myConn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & mySource &"; & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"
End With
myConn.Open

myRs.Open mySQLquery, myConn
```

Comment: The quotes in your connection string are not escaped properly. The embedded quotes around `"Data Source"` and `"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"` are not constructed correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put data containing double-quotes in string variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767037/how-to-put-data-containing-double-quotes-in-string-variable)

Comment: Thank you, Ken.  Those quotes are so annoying.  Here's the correct connection:
 .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & mySource & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";"