# Replacing/Deleting quotation marks from cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with quotation marks in excel file. I want to match strings from two excel files using vba, but one of the strings has additional "" eg.

In file 1: "ABC" Co.

In file 2: """ABC"" Co."

How can I delete this additional quotation marks from a cell. I've tried using Replace() function on both cells to delete all " marks and compare strings without it, but it doesn't work.

```
String = Replace(String, """, "")
```

Comment: String = Replace(String, """", "")

Comment: OR `replace(String,chr(34),"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace on """" instead of """ and it will work as intended. See [replace " in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452906/replace-in-vb-net) and answer by paxdiablo